# vi editor only works for first couple of characters than stops

Tags: git, vi, mingw32

after doing "git commit", I'm prompted to enter a commit message in vi editor.
I write a few characters (which are highlighted in yellow) but then at a certain number they stop and the writing goes to gray and when the change it submitted, the words in gray are left out.

Any ideas why and what can be done to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vi by default the first 50 characters of a commit message are shown in yellow, because that's the recommended right margin for git commit messages.

I don't think it's supposed to just chop off anything beyond 50 characters though. At least in my environment it doesn't. Check if you have a hook in the repository doing that.

Comment: Thank you. It worked the second time, maybe I was doing something wrong the first.